# How to specify switch parameter when calling a script from batch file

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, command-line-interface

I have a script `foo.ps1` and a batch file `foo.cmd` used to launch the script by double clicking the cmd file in file explorer.

The script accepts a switch parameter, but I don't know how to provide this kind of parameter. Simple parameters are ok.

Foo.ps1:

```
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [Switch]$MySwitch,
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$Name
)

Write-Host "`$MySwitch : $MySwitch, `$Name : $name"
```

Foo.cmd:

```
Powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -file "%~dp0\foo.ps1" -Name "abc"
```

If I call the script with only "Name", it works. But If I specify MySwitch, it stops to work:

Foo2.cmd:

```
Powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -File "%~dp0\foo.ps1" -Name "abc" -MySwitch:$false
```

The error is:

```
C:\temp\foo.ps1 : Impossible de traiter la transformation d'argument sur le paramètre «MySwitch». Impossible de convertir la valeur «System.String» en type « System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter». Les paramètres booléens acceptent seulement des valeurs booléennes et des nombres, tels que $True, $False, 1 ou 0.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData : (:) [foo.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,foo.ps1
```

Comment: I have worked around this in the past by using a `[String]` parameter with `ValidateSet("Yes","No")` (or something similar).

Comment: If you omit the `-MySwitch` parameter at all then it's the same as `-MySwitch:$false`. On the other side, `-MySwitch` is the same as `-MySwitch:$true`.

Comment: Another approach: `… -command "& '%~dp0\foo.ps1'  -Name 'a b c' -MySwitch:$false"` i.e. using `-command` instead of `-file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In *Windows PowerShell*, there is no way to pass *Boolean* values when [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s

`-File` parameter is used** - this has has since been corrected in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), whose CLI is [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)<sup>[1]</sup>.

Use the **workaround** that [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) recommends:

Use of **`-Command` (`-c`)** instead of `-File` **makes PowerShell treat the arguments as *PowerShell source code* rather than literal arguments**, in which case `$false` is properly recognized (other CLI parameters omitted for brevity).

```
powershell -c "& \"%~dp0\foo.ps1\" -Name 'abc' -MySwitch:$false"
```

Note:

- `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), must be used to invoke the script file, because its path is *quoted*.
- PowerShell expects embedded `"` chars. on the command line to be escaped as `\"` (not as `` `" `` or `""`, the way it works *inside* PowerShell).

  - With `-Command`, if you need to embed a verbatim `"` *inside an embedded `\"...\"` string*, use `` `\" `` (sic).
  - While you could enclose the script path in `'...'` instead, to avoid the need for escaping, such a call would break if the expanded directory file path (`%dp0`) happens to contain `'` chars. itself.
- For general guidance on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command` and the different syntax rules that apply, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).

---

**On a conceptual note**:

- Your code already uses the **preferred way to pass Boolean arguments in PowerShell: [`[switch]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#switch-parameters) parameters** (sometimes called *flags*).
- **Switch parameters *imply* Boolean values**: If a given switch - by name only - is specified (`-MySwitch`), `$true` is implied; if it is *absent altogether*, `$false` is implied. That is, **simply *omitting* `-MySwitch:$false` would have solved your problem too**.

  - By contrast, `[bool]`-typed parameters - which invariably *require* an argument - should be avoided. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49130184/45375) contrasts `[bool]` with `[switch]` parameters.
- While (PowerShell-internally) you (always) ***can* pass an *explicit* value** (as you tried with
  `-MySwitch:$false`, note the *required `:` separator*, a *space* wouldn't work) - doing so is **only *required* in the following scenarios**:

  - In case you want to pass a Boolean value *via a variable* whose value is determined *programmatically*.
  - In the rare case that a switch *defaults to `$true`*, and you need to override that.

    - For conceptual reasons, **defaulting switch parameters to `$true` is best avoided** in user code: if necessary, negate the logic of your switch; an example is `Write-Host`'s `-NoNewLine` switch.
    - However, some of PowerShell's [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) are switch parameters, which can *in effect* default to `$true` via their [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables) counterparts.

      - A notable example is the common [`-Confirm` switch parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-confirm): The value of the corresponding [`$ConfirmPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#confirmpreference) can make it necessary to pass `-Confirm:$false` in order to opt-out of a confirmation prompt, even with `$ConfirmPreference`'s default value (`High`).

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell (Core) 7+ supports the following Boolean values when `-File` is used: `$true`, `$false`, `true`, `false` (and also `$null`, but its interpretation differs: scripts (including with `-File`) and functions interpret it as `$false`, whereas cmdlets interpret it as `$true`(!)).

Note that with `-Command` - and therefore in all PowerShell code - `true` and `false` do *not* work, but `0` and `1` do.

Unfortunately, if you pass an unsupported value, you get the same error message in all scenarios, which in the `-File` scenario misleadingly suggests that `0` and `1` work too.</sup>